# Views dynamically added to TableLayout not showing

Tags: android, dynamic, android-tablelayout

I have a TableLayout in xml, and I want to add rows to it programmatically.

This is my code:

```
LinearLayout deckBuilder = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.deckbuilder, null);

TableLayout deckGrid = new TableLayout(this.getApplicationContext());

    int rows = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.deckbuilder_grid_rows);
    int columns = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.deckbuilder_grid_columns);

    deckGrid.setWeightSum(rows);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this.getApplicationContext());
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this.getApplicationContext());
            row.addView(iv);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
        }
        deckGrid.addView(row);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    }
    deckBuilder.addView(deckGrid);
    deckGrid.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

The problem is that the views I added in my rows are not showing up, the rows themselves are not showing up either.

Rows: 3, columns: 5.

Here is the xml for the deckbuilder:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/deckbuilder_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, first, you should not use applicationCOntext to create UI components and secondly did you printed out the value of rows and columns, if yes, please let us know the numbers and also it would be lot easier for us to help you if you would add here the xml for deckbuilder

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your code is inside a class that extends `Activity`.

So you should put

```
setContentView(deckBuilder);
```

after the last line to show the `LinearLayout`.

Moreover, inside an `Activity` you could use directly `this` in place of `this.getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: setContentView(deckBuilder) is done at the beginning of the class.
I have tried to use 'this' instead of this.getApplicationContext(), but it still didn't work